# Checking extension of a file using Cshell Scripting

Tags: shell, csh

I need to send a file as an argument to my C Shell Script. now I need to check whether it is a file with .xml extension or a file containing list of files with .xml extension.

Comment: If `$file` contains the name of the file (e.g., `foo.xml`), then `$file:e` gives the extension (`xml` in this case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a way to test this, but my past experience with csh tells me something like

```
 #!/bin/csh

 file="$1"

 switch ("$file")
     case *.xml:
         echo "file matches .xml"
      breaksw
     default:
         if ( grep '\.xml$' "$file" )  then
            echo "xml file extensions found in $file"
         endif
     breaksw
  endswitch
```

should work.

IHTH